# How to get a font awesome icon name when using click event on it?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So, if I do this in my HTML component:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="faSort" (click)="sort($event)"></fa-icon>
```

How will I get it's name in my ts component?

```
sort(event: Event) {???}
```

I tried doing it like this:

```
sort(event: Event) {

console.log(event['target']['ownerSVGElement']['classList'][1])

}
```

But the method above is very inconsistent. Is there a better way of doing this?

Font Awesome Package Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome

Comment: What about `sort($event, 'faSort')` then `sort(event, name)`?

Comment: Is there a way where I won't have to manually specify its name as an argument?

Comment: You already do though? With `[name]=“faSort”`

Comment: @ab1004 did my answer solve your problem? If so, please mark it as the correct answer for future users who run into similar issues

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't really care about anything else that the event value may contain within it.

```
sort(event : any) {
   console.log("Icon Name: ", event.iconName);
}

<fa-icon [icon]="faSort" (click)="sort({ iconName: 'faSort'})"></fa-icon>
```

Assuming you still want to capture the actual event itself:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="faSort" (click)="sort({event: $event, iconName: 'faIcon'})"></fa-icon>
```

The reason this works is that we allow our sort to accept a type of any, and we are creating a brand new object using the curly braces.